# Pass data from a VC without Segue to a non VC Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I passed data from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2` via segue, but how can I send data to the `Class`? This class is not a ViewController.

- `ViewController1` has a `UIPickerView` that gives the data (String).
- The String will complete an URL needed in `ViewController2`.

**Class**

```
class A: SendDataFromDelegate {

func sendData(data: String) {
    self.data = data
}

var delegate : SendDataFromDelegate?
```

**ViewController1**

```
@IBAction func Picker(_ sender: Any) {
     var delegate: SendDataFromDelegate?
     delegate?.sendData(data: data)
    }

protocol  SendDataFromDelegate {
   func sendData(data : String)
   }
```

Is this a good way to do it?

Or should I create all the possible URLs in the `class`, and call them from `ViewController2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a protocol with delegate functions like this:

```
protocol ClassDelegate: class {
  func doSomething()
}
```

In your class A you should implement that protocol this way:

```
class A: ClassDelegate {
  inAFunction(){
    ViewController1.delegate = self
  }

  func sendData(data: String) {
    self.data = data
  }
}
```

In the viewController you want to send data to your Class A you should have reference of your class A and use the delegate variable:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: ClassDelegate?
  func clickHere(){
    delegate.sendData()
  }
}
```

When you use clickHere function it triggers Class C sendData function.

Try it ;D

Comment: Thank you, somehow I am not able to call the delegate: ViewController1.delegate = self

Comment: Do you have an instance of class A in your ViewController1? If so you can do this: `delegate = instanceOfClassA` . You have to link both classes with the delegate to make it work.